# Batch File to delete files from the folder whose filenames not mentioned in the XML file

Tags: batch-file

Working on a batch file from past 2 days but no luck :(

I am in need of a script (Bat) that will delete all projects (mostly vb) not mentioned in my build list (xml).

Eg: I have a folder named C:\123 which has around 15 files in it.
I have a build list (XML file) which has 10 filenames which are there in C:\123. Now I want a batch file script which will delete the rest 5 files from C:\123 which is not there in the xml file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
script tried to compare 2 folders and delete the identical files first (thought of tweaking it later according to my need but this didn't work)

```
@ECHO OFF

SET LOCALFOLDER=C:\123
SET OTHERFOLDER=D:\123

Pause
:LOCALKEYTEMP

SET FILE=DONE

:: THIS LINE SCANS THE LOCAL FOLDER FOR FILES, 
:: WE CAN USE THIS TO SCAN SEPERATE FILES ONE AT A 

TIME

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%G IN ('DIR/B ^"%LOCALFOLDER%

\*.*^"') DO SET FILE=%%G
Pause
ECHO %FILE%
pause

IF %FILE%==DONE GOTO END
pause

ECHO N|COMP "%LOCALFOLDER%\%FILE%" 

"%OTHERFOLDER%\%FILE%" | FIND "FILES COMPARE OK" > 

NUL
pause

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO DIFFERENTKEYS
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO DELETEBOTH
pause

DELETEBOTH

DEL /Q "%LOCALFOLDER%\%FILE%"
DEL /Q "%OTHERFOLDER%\%FILE%"

GOTO LOCALKEYTEMP


DIFFERENTKEYS

:: THIS LINE DELETES THE LOCAL FOLDERS FILES WHICH IS 

NECCESSARY FOR THIS SCRIPT

DEL /Q "%LOCALFOLDER%\%FILE%"

GOTO LOCALKEYTEMP


:END
ECHO ALL FILES SHOULD BE DELETED FROM 

%LOCALFOLDER%
pause
ECHO ALL DIFFERENT FILES SHOULD BE LEFT ON 

%OTHERFOLDER%
PAUSE

EXIT
```

xml file looks like:

```
<ProjectsToBuild>
    <Project>C:\123\Clients\Direct\App1.vbproj</Project>                      
    <Project>C:\123\Clients\Direct\App2.vbproj</Project> 
</ProjectsToBuild>
```

result of the Aacini's Batch Script:

```
Press any key to continue . . .
List of existent files:
fileName[D:\123\Subfolder1\a1.txt.txt]=1
fileName[D:\123\Subfolder1\a2.txt.txt]=1
fileName[D:\123\Subfolder1\a3.txt.txt]=1
fileName[D:\123\Subfolder1\a4.txt.txt]=1
fileName[D:\123\Subfolder1\buildList.xml]=1
fileName[D:\123\Subfolder2\a1.txt.txt]=1
fileName[D:\123\Subfolder2\a2.txt.txt]=1
fileName[D:\123\Subfolder2\a3.txt.txt]=1
fileName[D:\123\Subfolder2\a4.txt.txt]=1
fileName[D:\123\Subfolder2\buildList.xml]=1
Press any key to continue . . .

Keep these files:
Press any key to continue . . .

Remove these files:
Press any key to continue . . .
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This deletes all the files in the folder.

Comment: You need to provide us two things. 1) What you have tried so far and 2) How your build list XML looks like.

Comment: @adarshhr Thanks for your response Adarsh..I tried comparing the contents of two folders and deleting the identical files first. thought of tweaking it later as per my need. but this doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Can you show how the XML looks like? Sorry, I won't be able to help you without seeing that.

Comment: `<ProjectsToBuild> <Project>C:\123\Clients\Direct\App1.vbproj</Project> <Project>C:\123\Clients\Direct\App2.vbproj</Project> </ProjectsToBuild>`

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me. In your question you said "I have a folder named C:\123 which has around 15 files *in it*"; however, the build list just have two names that are in folders *two levels down* below C:\123. Indeed, C:\123 folder have no one file mentioned in build list. I assumed that you want to delete all files in C:\123 *at any level* that are not mentioned in the build list (because the build list mention files two levels down below C:\123). If this is not what you want, then the Batch file must be modified.

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem Create a list of existent file names in C:\123 *at any level*
for /R "C:\123" %%a in (*.*) do set "fileName[%%a]=1"
ECHO List of existent files:
SET fileName[
ECHO/
rem Process the build list and remove found names from existent files list
ECHO Keep these files:
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=<>" %%a in (buildList.xml) do (
   if "%%a" == "Project" if "%%c" == "/Project" (
      ECHO fileName[%%b]
      set "fileName[%%b]="
   )
)
ECHO/
ECHO Remove these files:
rem Remove the remaining files
for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('set fileName[') do (
   ECHO del "%%a"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. My apologies. Yes, I want to  delete all files in C:\123\ at any level that are not mentioned in the build list indeed!!! The tree in this case will be C:\123 and the subfolders - \Clients, \Direct etc. The batch file must be able to traverse to through the subfolders, check and delete the files which are not present in the build list. I tried your script above but it doesn't seem to work for me :( plz help.

Comment: @ashishg: I have added some `ECHO` commands to show what is happening. Please, copy again the Batch file above, execute it and post the results.

Comment: I've posted the result of the script.

Comment: @ashishg: Note that last command is `ECHO del ...` that only show the command to execute as a test. When you are sure the Batch file is right, remove the `ECHO ` part so the command be `del ...` and DO delete the files!

Comment: I want to keep the files which are there in the build list(xml) and delete the rest. The code actually "deletes all" the files if I remove the ECHO in the last line. The xml file looks like: <ProjectsToBuild> <Project>D:\123\SubFolder1\h1.txt</Project> <Project>D:\123\SubFolder1\h2.txt</Project> <Project>D:\123\SubFolder2\h1.txt</Project> <Project>D:\123\SubFolder2\h2.txt</Project> </ProjectsToBuild>

Comment: @ashishg: Your build list does NOT mention a single file in C:\123 folder! Mentioned files are in D:\123 folder (a different drive). Do you want to _ignore_ the drive of the files in the build list?

Comment: Also, in your previous examples <Project> lines have spaces at left. If the real lines have not spaces at left, a modification in the Batch file is needed.

Comment: Plz ignore the drive of the files in build list. It was just for an example sake I mentioned them (You can consider either of them C:\ or D:\). Also, plz ignore the spaces on left of <Project> lines.

Comment: @ashishg: You must understand that Batch files are not as flexible as other programming languages and usually are developed under specific constraints. The Batch file above was written in accordance with your previous description and examples. Please, run the above Batch file _with your real data_ and post the result as an edit in your question, _not as an answer_. If there are no names under **Keep these files** message, then the <Project> lines have no spaces at left...

Comment: Could you please tell me how do I remove spaces for <project> lines. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @ashishg: This command: `for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=<>" %%a...` assume that file names in build list have this format: "    <Project>C:\123\Clients\Direct\App1.vbproj</Project>" like in your "xml file looks like:" comment above, that is: "spaces<Project>filename</Project>" processed as "token1<token2>token3</token4>". If lines in build list have really this format: "<Project>filename</Project>", then the command should be: `for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=<>" %%a...`. You have NOT posted the _real_ xml file, so I can only guess... :(